# Threads don't seem to be running concurrently with shared read only data

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

I have some knowledge of CS, but I am a beginner programmer and certainly have no experience with parallel computing.

The financial simulation I am writing traverses 60 days with ~1,000,000 lines of data per day stored in vectors.  Each day is read-only and being treated independently inside the main loop so I thought some parallelization could really speed things up.  Unfortunately all my threads seem to be running sequentially with no improvement in execution time.

I replicated some threading examples I saw on this site and did see some parallelization but when I added the shared data this disappeared and the threads ran sequentially.

My original program is pretty large so I tried to distill the code below.

As you can see, the first column is being completely 'processed' before the next.  Shouldn't the output have SOME interleaving between threads?  At the very least, the next thread should Begin: before the previous thread ends?  Is it a caching thing?  Getting this working should cut processing time by 75%, but it is actually taking longer.

In my original program I implemented some very simple locking, but I didn't include it here as the problem seems to exist without it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
//ThreadTest.h

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#pragma once

using namespace std;

extern mutex test_lock;

class Storage {
public:
    Storage(int rows, int cols) {
        data.resize(cols);
        for (vector<vector<string>>::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++) {
            i->resize(rows);
        }
        for (vector<vector<string>>::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++) {
            for (vector<string>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++) {
                *j = to_string(i - data.begin()) + " " + to_string(j - i->begin());
            }
        }
    }

    vector<vector<string>> data;
};

class ThreadTest {
public:
    ThreadTest() {
        fout.open("TESTOUT.txt");
    }

    ofstream fout;
    void storage_work(const vector<string>& column);
    void loop(const vector<vector<string>>& data);
};
```

---

```
//ThreadTest.cpp
#include "ThreadTest.h"

mutex test_lock;

void ThreadTest::storage_work(const vector<string>& column)
{
    fout << "Begin: \n";
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = column.begin(); i != column.end(); i++) {
        if ((i - column.begin()) % 100000 == 0) fout << ":" << *i << " \n";
    }
    fout << "End: \n";
}

void ThreadTest::loop(const vector<vector<string>>& data)
{
    vector<thread> thread_list;

    for (vector<vector<string>>::const_iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++) {
        thread_list.emplace_back(&ThreadTest::storage_work, this, *i);
    }
    fout << "thread_list.size() : " << thread_list.size() << endl;
    for (vector<thread>::iterator i = thread_list.begin(); i != thread_list.end(); i++) {
        i->join();
    }
}
```

---

```
//Source.cpp
#include "ThreadTest.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ThreadTest t;
    Storage s(1000000, 10);
    t.loop(s.data);
}
```

---

```
//TESTOUT.txt
Begin: 
:0 0 
:0 100000 
:0 200000 
:0 300000 
:0 400000 
:0 500000 
:0 600000 
:0 700000 
:0 800000 
:0 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:1 0 
:1 100000 
:1 200000 
:1 300000 
:1 400000 
:1 500000 
:1 600000 
:1 700000 
:1 800000 
:1 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:2 0 
:2 100000 
:2 200000 
:2 300000 
:2 400000 
:2 500000 
:2 600000 
:2 700000 
:2 800000 
:2 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:3 0 
:3 100000 
:3 200000 
:3 300000 
:3 400000 
:3 500000 
:3 600000 
:3 700000 
:3 800000 
:3 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:4 0 
:4 100000 
:4 200000 
:4 300000 
:4 400000 
:4 500000 
:4 600000 
:4 700000 
:4 800000 
:4 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:5 0 
:5 100000 
:5 200000 
:5 300000 
:5 400000 
:5 500000 
:5 600000 
:5 700000 
:5 800000 
:5 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:6 0 
:6 100000 
:6 200000 
:6 300000 
:6 400000 
:6 500000 
:6 600000 
:6 700000 
:6 800000 
:6 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:7 0 
:7 100000 
:7 200000 
:7 300000 
:7 400000 
:7 500000 
:7 600000 
:7 700000 
:7 800000 
:7 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:8 0 
:8 100000 
:8 200000 
:8 300000 
:8 400000 
:8 500000 
:8 600000 
:8 700000 
:8 800000 
:8 900000 
End: 
Begin: 
:9 0 
thread_list.size() : 10
:9 100000 
:9 200000 
:9 300000 
:9 400000 
:9 500000 
:9 600000 
:9 700000 
:9 800000 
:9 900000 
End:
```

Comment: The work happening in the thread is almost nothing.  It is likely that the work finishes so quickly that the next thread hasn't spawned yet.  You can see that your main thread debug output happens in the middle of thread 9, so it *is* happening asynchronously.

Comment: BTW since you're using C++11, a few extra language features will make your code much more readable: `for (auto &t : thread_list) t.join();`

Comment: Thank you for your help, the loop in my original program is a lot heftier, but maybe something like this is happening there as well.

Comment: I would put a small `sleep()` in your test function

Comment: Problem solved!  You were right that I was spawning threads in an inner loop that didn't do tons of work.  However a larger (newbie) problem was I didn't realize I had to ref() wrap my inputs.  The copy constructor was being called millions of times.